# Most "Pythonic" (or "Pandathonic") way to iterate through DataFrame and create groupings

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently refactoring some old code. One section of the code iterates through a very large sorted dataframe of webpage activity that looks generally like this:

```
Index | User | Time   |   Session_name  |  Session_num
1,       ABC,   11:52,        "",            ""  
2,       ABC,   12:31,        "",            ""    
3,       DEF,   7:30,         "",            ""  
4,       DEF,   12:30,        "",            ""  
....
```

The current code looks like this:

```
x = 60 # number of minutes between two interactions that are considered same session
session_ID = df['User'][0] + df['Time'][0]
session_num = 1
for i in df.index[1:]:
     if(df['User'][i-1] == df['User'][i]) & ((df['Time'][i] -df['Time'][i-1]) < x):
        df.loc[i, 'session_name'] = session_ID
        df.loc[i, 'session_number'] = session_num
     else:
         session_ID = CombinedGALogDF['User_ID'][i] + "," + CombinedGALogDF['Timestamp'][i]
        session_num += 1
        df.loc[i, 'session_name'] = session_ID
        df.loc[i, 'session_number'] = session_num
```

What this code accomplishes: goes through all of the actions a user took and tags them to a session (which is defined as all actions by the same user without a 60+min gap between them). For example if User ABC clicked on a link at 11:01, 11:52, and 12:43 those would all be part of the same session and should be tagged "ABC 11:01". I am unclear on how to recreate this chained name effect without iterating through each row

The major issue is that this takes almost 10 minutes and there are multiple blocks of code like it. I have done some reading and found that iterating through the rows of a panda dataframe is the slowest way to perform an operation like this. My first idea to fix this was to create two temporary columns with the User and Time shifted down one to facilitate a comparison. Any and all help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: are you trying to aggregate by the groups? `df.groupby(['User']).<aggregation>`

Comment: Good question, I should have been more explicit. I am trying to go through and tag each event to a user session which I am defining as all activities in the database with the same User and timestamps less than 60 minutes apart. The output would be each event (timestamp occurrence) being tagged to a session ID (User + timestamp when the session started) and a session num which is just an iterated count up. The difficult thing here is that the sessions can be chained as in if you click on a link at 11:01, 11:52, and 12:43 those are all part of the same "session" and should be named "ABC 11:01"